# Load div when clicked on list item

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have a question. I’m making a one page design website at the moment, and in one div there’s a loader where you can see what my skills are. It's an animated circle. The problem is that the loader already loads when you're on the website. But I want it to load when you click on the list item 'Skills'. So that's the third list item called #blok3.

```
<div id="menu">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#blok1">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blok2">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blok3">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blok4">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blok5">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

Below is the script of the skills loader. Als you can see in the Javascript part there are 5 id's but below I putted one because the other 5 are all te same, except the name #myStat...

```
<div class="statistic">
  <div id="myStat1" data-dimension="150" data-text="Ai" data-info="" data-width="15" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="85" data-fgcolor="#FFF" data-bgcolor="#A7E3E7"></div>
  <div class="statistic-text">Illustrator</div>  
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#myStat1').circliful();
        $('#myStat2').circliful();
        $('#myStat3').circliful();
        $('#myStat4').circliful();
        $('#myStat5').circliful();
        $('#myStat6').circliful();
    });
</script>
```

I tried some things with the knowledge that I have, but it didn't work. I hope someone can help me. Thank you :)

When I don't use any code the loader looks like this:

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=rh1ydc&s=8#.U2T5OK00SjU

When I use the code from Krish R the loader looks like this (look at the picture below). There appear more circles, but it starts loading when you click on Skills, so that's the good part. But I don't need the double circles of course ;)

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1690txz&s=8#.U2T5Va00SjU

Comment: we don't see here how your javascript code relates to your html. please try to reproduce the problem with the minimum code possible, and post the code in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the code to animate the circle in a function that is called on (executed), when the list item is clicked... As `$( document ).ready(function()` means that your code should execute at the instant the page loads! :D 


Example:


Code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Circle</title>
<script>
function skill()
{
    // the code to animate circle
    alert('animated circle!');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#blok1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blok2">About</a></li>
        <li>
        <a onclick = "skill()" href="#blok3">
        Skills
        </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#blok4">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blok5">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

*Tested in:* Firefox 24, Google Chrome 34


**Update:**

Since we don't have access to the circle animation code, we could completely remove it, and when `Skills` is clicked, we dynamically put it in using JavaScript's `innerHTML` .

**Example**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<title>Circle</title>
<script>
function skill()
{
    var anim = document.getElementById('anim');
    anim.innerHTML = '<div id="myStat1" data-dimension="150" data-text="Ai" data-info=""   `data-width="15" data-fontsize="38" data-percent="85" data-fgcolor="#FFF" data-bgcolor="#A7E3E7"></div><div class="statistic-text">Illustrator</div>  ';`
    $('#myStat1').circliful();
    $('#myStat2').circliful();
    $('#myStat3').circliful();
    $('#myStat4').circliful();
    $('#myStat5').circliful();
    $('#myStat6').circliful();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#blok1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blok2">About</a></li>
        <li onclick = "skill()">
        <a onclick = "skill()" href="#blok3">
        Skills
        </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#blok4">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blok5">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="statistic" id = "anim">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this code, but nothing seems to happen. When I click on Skills the circles are already loaded.

Comment: @user3598842 Then please accept my answer (click the tick icon at it) so other users can see it... Glad I helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

Javascript:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {            
        Loadcircliful();
        $("#myskills").click(function(){
            Loadcircliful();
            return false;
        });
    });

    function Loadcircliful(){           
        $('#myStat1, #myStat2, #myStat3, #myStat4, #myStat5, #myStat6').circliful();
    }
```

in html,

```
    <li><a href="#blok3" id="myskills">Skills</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, and when I click on Skills it starts to load, but the loaders overlap each other. I don't know why that is. So when I click again on Skills more circles appear.

Comment: can you provide the jsfiddle with circle code! Am not sure what is the issue

Comment: I tried it with jsfiddle but didn't work out so well. I don't know how I can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

may be this works for you...

in your html

```
  <li id="blok3"><a href="#blok3">Skills</a></li>
```

in your javascript

```
  $('#blok3').click(function () {  $('#myStat3').circliful(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: no, it does not, is just to show you a way to proceed. You have to put some effort to read the code, understand it and adapt it to include it in your code.